# How can I fix these browser console warnings I get using bootstrap react?

Tags: react-bootstrap

I get this console warnings when I run my react app using bootstrap react. I believe they are from the LinkContainer I use in my navigation page. But how can I fix this?

```
warning.js:36 Warning: Unknown prop `active` on <a> tag. Remove this prop from the element. 
in a (at index.js:18)
in LinkContainer (created by IndexLinkContainer)
in IndexLinkContainer (at index.js:17)
in NavbarBrand (at index.js:16)
in div (created by NavbarHeader)
in NavbarHeader (at index.js:15)
in div (created by Grid)
in Grid (created by Navbar)
in nav (created by Navbar)
in Navbar (created by Uncontrolled(Navbar))
in Uncontrolled(Navbar) (at index.js:13)
in div (at index.js:12)
in Appnav (created by RouterContext)
in RouterContext (created by Router)
in Router (at index.js:49)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you may know `<a>` doesn't have `active` attribute and you are passing this from your react component.

What you should do instead is extract all the props that are not valid attributes and use them as you wish

```
const {active, ...attributes} = this.props;

// do what you need with `active`

return (
    <a {...attributes} />
)
```

Comment: The <a> in this case is not mine. I import a LinkContainer from react-router-bootstrap which is in my dependencies. I thought this was something the guys supporting that library should be aware of and that they could supply a fix.

Comment: you must see the compatibility in their git repository, you must be using a newest reactjs version than them.